# Python to list all primes 50 - 1000 , then squaring and checking if prime

Tags: python, primes

I would like to write a program to list all prime numbers 50 - 1000 and then square each of the identified primes and perform a check if any of the numbers are prime or composite.

I have the below code working to list all primes, I am not entirely sure where to start to perform the second check to square the prime numbers and check if prime or composite. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
lower = 50
upper = 1000

print("Prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are:")

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
   # all prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2, num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
```

Comment: what is the *error*, add the traceback. the `else` is off by a couple of spaces.

Comment: A square can *never* be prime, by definition.

Comment: Why bother to check if a number of the form `p^2` is prime? It isn't. On the other hand, doing so could have some limited value for testing your code's ability to recognize composite numbers.

Comment: Extract the inner code into a separate `is_prime()` function. Then you can use it with the original number and the squared number.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a square can not be prime. However, if you want to test it by your own, I have rewritten your by creating a function called `check_prime()` which checks whether the number is prime.

```
def check_prime(number):
    temp = []
    for i in range(1, number):
        if len(temp) > 1:
            return False
        if number % i == 0:
            temp.append(i)
    return True
prime = []
for i in range(50, 101):
    if check_prime(i):
        prime.append(i)
prime_2 = []
for i in prime:
    if check_prime(i ** 2):
        prime_2.append(i ** 2)
print(prime_2)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the same thing I was going to do. =D

Comment: What's the purpose of the `temp` list? Why not do `return False` instead of appending to it?

Comment: Shouldn't the second loop be `check_prime(i*i)`?

Comment: @Barmar purpose of the function is to make it runnable in many cases. By determining whether the number is prime by returning `True` or `False` you can use that function not only for that task, but also for another. The function takes 1 numbers, instead of list.

Comment: I understand the purpose of the function. I don't understand the purpose of the `temp` list in the function. After you append to it, the next iteration returns `False`. But you can just return `False` immediately.

Comment: I think I see why you need that. Because you're starting your loop from `1` instead of `2`. You're checking for `len(temp) > 1` so you don't count `1`, which will always be a divisor. But it would simpler to just change to `range(2, ceil(math.sqrt(number)))`

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `check_prime(i ** 2)` (or the second loop in general) since i**2  will never be prime, so prime2 will always be an empty list.

Comment: @DarrylG the intention of OP was to make program that checks whether the square will be prime. As I mentioned in an answer, it will not ever be, but if he wants to check it by himself, here is the code to do that.